# How to convert a java Map to immutable Scala map via java code?

Tags: java, scala, collections, scala-collections

I need to create a  immutable Scala map with java code. I have found other things on here about this but nothing that is updated to the current version.

I've tried:

```
public static <A, B> Map<A, B> toScalaMap(HashMap<A, B> m) {
        return JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter(m).asScala().toMap(
                Predef.<Tuple2<A, B>>conforms()
        );
}
```

Comment: What's the bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve?  Why do you want a Scala map in Java code?

Comment: I am working with the kafka AdminClient class which returns a collections.scala.immutable.Map and I want to be able to create one so I can have a mock return it in a unit test.

Comment: so, what happened when you tried it?

Comment: I get cannot find symbol: Predef.<Tuple2<A, B>>conforms()

Comment: Try `scala.Predef.conforms<Tuple2<A,B>>()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed conforms to $conforms and it now runs find in both Intellij and the command line but Intellij still give a red line under JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter(m).asScala().toMap( that says cannot access scala.Predef.$less$colon$colon.

```
private   <A,B> scala.collection.immutable.Map<A, B> toScalaMap(Map<A, B> m) {
        return JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter(m).asScala().toMap(
                Predef.$conforms()
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It worked ! Wondering why Intellij throws that error

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. The problem is likely an issue with how you're building or running your code, or perhaps you don't have all the necessary imports. The following works with version 4.6.1 of the Scala IDE for Eclipse and Scala 2.12:

```
package org.soreadytohelp;

import java.util.HashMap;

import scala.Predef;
import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;
import scala.collection.immutable.Map;

public class MapTest {
    public static <A, B> Map<A, B> toScalaMap(HashMap<A, B> m) {
        return JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter(m).asScala().toMap(
            Predef.<Tuple2<A, B>>conforms()
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("food", "bacon");

        Map<String, String> hmAsScala = toScalaMap(hm);
        System.out.println(hmAsScala);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with IntelliJ, but it turned out to be just an IntelliJ compiler error and was able to run via maven just fine. Try running/building your code to see if its just a compiler error.